# Retrieve field based on record field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 3 tables 
items,
item_units,
order_items

First table items has the list of items that can be ordered.

Second table item_units has units for the items as well as the amount of those items in this unit

Third table has items that were ordered... ie... item_code , unit, qty

Here are the columns for items

```
   [item_code]
  ,[desc]
```

Here are the columns for item_units

```
  ,[item_code]
  ,[unit]
  ,[amount]
  ,[price]
  ,[default_sprd_sht]
```

Here are the columns for order_items

```
  ,[order_id]
  ,[item_code]
  ,[item_desc]
  ,[unit]
  ,[qty]
  ,[price]
```

Note the [default_sprd_sht]. This field is a boolean. If it's set to true this unit is never put into order_items table. This field will be used as calculation field.

For example:
If 1 customer orders 2 6 packs of bread and another orders 3 dozens of bread, the baker needs to know how many pans of bread to make.
Now a 6 pack unit has 6 breads as amount, meaning 2 * 6 = 12. And a dozen unit has 12 breads.. 12 * 3 = 36. A pan bread unit has 20 breads. So i need to add up all the bread units amounts and divide them by the pan amount like so

`((2*6) + (12 * 3)) / 20 = 2.4`

So the first thing I did to create a report for the baker was

Create a group for `order_items.item_code` and then `order_item.unit.`

This needs to be done since the same item and unit cobination will be repeated in different orders. The baker needs to see how many bagels or breads he needs to bake in total.

in the `order_item.unit` group header I created a formula field that multiplies the `order_item.unit by item.amount`

```
Sum ({order_items.qty}, {order_items.unit}) * {items_units.amount}
```

That was easy.
But I aslo need to group all order items if there exists a record in the items_units with the same item_code and with [default_sprd_sht] set to true

This would look like so

```
(Sum ({order_items.qty}, {order_items.unit}) * {items_units.amount}) / (get amount for unit with the same item_code and [default_sprd_sht] = 1)
```

I have two problems accomplishing this.

1. How to check if this order item has a unit with same item_code and
   [default_sprd_sht] = 1?
2. How to further group order items only if there is a unit with same
   item_code and [default_sprd_sht] = 1?

Comment: huge explanation what exactly you need.. can you explain in few words?

Comment: The last three sentences pretty much does that.